# GWT - DialogBox.center() doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, gwt

There's a table with buttons on my page. There're so much buttons, that I have a scroller to scroll down my table.

Button "onClick" generates a dialog box with scrollpanel, content and a button to close this dialog box. I center it using DialogBox.center(). When I press, let's say the first button in a table, dialog box appears strictly in the center.... but when I scroll down the page and press button in the bottom of my table, my DialogBox still appears in the "old" center...almost above my view. It simply doesn't move down according to my scrollbar position.
I tried to change setPopupPosition(), setPopupPositionAndShow() and so on, but it didn't help.

Is there any ideas what is wrong? Here is some code of my dialog box:

```
public class MyDialogBox extends DialogBox {

    public MyDialogBox(final String caption, final String text) {
        setText("Caption: " + caption);

        VerticalPanel inner = new VerticalPanel();
        Label msg = new Label(text);

        Button ok = new Button("Close");
        ok.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    MessageTextBox.this.hide();
                }
        });

        inner.add(msg);
        ScrollPanel scrollbar = new ScrollPanel(inner);
        scrollbar.setSize("640", "480");
        VerticalPanel outer = new VerticalPanel();
        outer.add(scrollbar);
        outer.add(ok);
        setWidget(outer);
    }
}
```

And here is how my button call it:

```
VerticalPanel mainPanel ... //MainPanel with a lot different elements, it contains panel with buttons
VerticalPanel panel ... //Panel with buttons
panel.setViewButtonHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        MyDialogBox dialogBox = new MyDialogBox("Caption", "Some text");
        dialogBox.center();
        dialogBox.show();
     }
});
mainPanel.add(panel);
```

Comment: It is centered the first time and as you scroll down (on the browser) you want the dialog box to move down with the scrolling and stay centered?

Comment: No. I want it always appear in the center of the page inspite of button I press - on the top of the table, in the middle or in the bottom.
But now dialog box appears in the center only if I press button on the top of the table. I'd attach a screenshot of such nonsense, but I don't know how.

Comment: but in your description you are saying that you want to move the dialogbox to the new center according to your scroll position. This is why I asked. I used dialog box a lot and the .center() works fine. Maybe you should try different browsers and different html standard setting..maybe it is a browser issue.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Everything is correct at me, it is the problem of Google Chrome browser :( Firefox process this simple functionality well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of mentioned problem appeared to be very simple. Chrome doesn't center dialog box correctly. I checked with FF, IE... and it works as it was planned.