# centering an element in the decorative popup panel in gwt

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

[image]

the pop up is a decorative pop up , the text in it is a label and close is a button.
i have added the label and a button to horizontal panel and then added it to popup panel. i have tried with both invalidEntryVpanel.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
invalidEntryVpanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

but still not able to align it in center please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

You have to add the widgets after you set the `align center`

```java
VerticalPanel vpnPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        vpnPanel.add(scrollPanel);   //all controls added to scrill panel with help of set widget 
        vpnPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
        HorizontalPanel btnLayoutPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        btnLayoutPanel.setSpacing(10);
        btnLayoutPanel.add(closeButton);
        vpnPanel.add(btnLayoutPanel);
        decPopuppanel.setWidget(vpnPanel);
```

Comment: thank you but now i have bigger problem i have set the popUpPanel.center() but still the popup shifts to bit right

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723855/gwt-dialogbox-center-doesnt-work-correctly

Comment: i followed it but still of no use even in ie .. its not setting to center.. any other way of doing it?

Comment: dialogBox.setPopupPosition(left, top)